# geom_text posicionando os rótulo individualmente

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estou fazendo um gráfico parecido com este do exemplo, onde posiciono os rótulos por grupo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Estou usando o código:

```
set.seed(1000)

ano=factor(rep(1996:2016,2))
cod=c(rep("K1",21),rep("O1.3",21))
valor=round(c(cumsum(rnorm(21)),cumsum(cumsum(rnorm(21)))),1)

dat=data.frame(cod,ano,valor)

ggplot(dat,aes(x=ano,y=valor, group=cod, color=cod, label=valor)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = cod), size=0.5) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=cod), size=2.5) +
  geom_text(data=subset(dat,cod=="K1"), aes(y = valor + 2), size=3) + 
  geom_text(data=subset(dat,cod=="O1.3"), aes(y = valor - 2), size=3) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "darkblue")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y  = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

O resultado que eu gostaria é que a posição dos rótulos acompanhasse os respectivos pontos, ou seja, quando a linha azul está acima de linha vermelha, os rótulos correspondentes azuis estão próximos aos respectivos pontos, acima deles, e vice-versa. O mesmo para a linha vermelha. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando em conjunto as excelentes soluções recebidas cheguei ao seguinte código:

```
mult = 2*(dat[dat$cod==rots[1], 3] > dat[dat$cod==rots[2], 3])-1
dat$pos=c(mult,mult*(-1))

ggplot(dat,aes(x=ano,y=valor, group=cod, color=cod, label=valor)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = cod), size=0.5) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=cod), size=2.5) +
  geom_text(data=dat, aes(y = valor + dat$pos*desloc), size=3,
            show.legend = FALSE) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "darkblue")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y  = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        axis.title.y = 
          element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 20, b = 0, l = 0)))
```

Comment: A partir da tua resposta não é possível entender o conteúdo de `rots`

Answer (score 6):

O que você precisa fazer é utilizar o argumento `nudge_y` de `geom_text`. Você deve passar um vetor de valores de mesmo comprimento do original. Segue código:

```
# Cria as posições
dat$pos <- c(ifelse(dat[dat$cod=="K1", 3] > dat[dat$cod=="O1.3", 3], 1, -1),
  ifelse(dat[dat$cod=="O1.3", 3] > dat[dat$cod=="K1", 3], 1, -1))

ggplot(dat,aes(x=ano,y=valor, group=cod, color=cod, label=valor)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = cod), size=0.5) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=cod), size=2.5) +
  geom_text(data=dat, aes(y = valor), size=3, nudge_y = dat$pos) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "darkblue")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y  = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em casos de sobreposição (para diferente valores do `set.seed()`, basta alterar a regra.

Comment: Excelente solução. Notei que utilizando um valor maior do que 1 em "dat$pos <- c(ifelse(dat[dat$cod=="K1", 3] > dat[dat$cod=="O1.3", 3], 1, -1),
  ifelse(dat[dat$cod=="O1.3", 3] > dat[dat$cod=="K1", 3], 1, -1))" recebo o seguinte aviso: "Warning message:
In if (params$y != 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used". Alguma sugestão?

Comment: `dat$pos <- c(ifelse(dat[dat$cod=="K1", 3] > dat[dat$cod=="O1.3", 3], 3, -3),
             ifelse(dat[dat$cod=="O1.3", 3] > dat[dat$cod=="K1", 3], 3, -3))` funciona perfeitamente para mim.

Answer (score 3):

Tente o seguinte. O truque é encontrar um multiplicador para a distância a somar à posição `y` no `geom_text`, neste caso `2`. Vou fazer isso com `ave`.

```
mult <- ave(dat$valor, dat$ano, FUN = function(x) 2*(x[1] < x[2]) - 1)
mult <- mult*(2*(dat$cod != "K1") - 1)

ggplot(dat,aes(x=ano,y=valor, group=cod, color=cod, label=valor)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = cod), size=0.5) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=cod), size=2.5) +
  geom_text(aes(y = valor + mult*2), size=3) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "darkblue")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y  = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]